# How to read Xamarin Xaml x:Name in code behind C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I thought it would be a great to be able to generate automated ids based on x:Name values, which could be set in custom controls.

However I’ve not be able to find a way to retrieve the x:Name in code.

Just for clarity I’m using our CustomButton and CustomLabel controls for all buttons and labels etc.

Comment: You can't.  The XAML compiler generates variable names using the x:Name value that reference the control, but the control itself doesn't know what it's name is.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I suspected it might not be accessible, seemed like a common question without any answers.

Comment: My questions is why do you want to do that? My reaction is that you probably don't want to use XAML at all if you're doing whatever it is that needs these automated IDs. If you create the custom controls programmatically you'll naturally have references to them anyway, without having to worry about x:Name, won't you?

Comment: @RobotHead it’s just that most controls have names already, just seems a shame to litter xaml with almost identical attributes.

Comment: I manage all my AutomationIDs in a resx file, and then use them as StaticResource in my Xaml files. But you can also define AutomationIDs in a static class like in this [code sample](https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/6e67372cde7e5167a7f2296b6a22bbf6176b9fa8/Src/UITestSampleApp.Shared/Constants/AutomationIdConstants.cs#L3).

Comment: Yeah I think constants is the way to go, which I can use in code behind and I’m ui testing. But it’s a shame I can’t generate them without having to define each automated id.

Comment: Yes I understand, I would recommend you to edit your question so that it describes your actual need. I would also be interested to know if you have an answer to your question ! :)

Comment: Do you want to define AutomationID in codebehind by x:Name ?

Comment: Yes, in the parent Custom control

Comment: Maybe you could show some codes of your Custom control,as far as I know you should be able to set AutomationID as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for example a button set in XAML file :

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="Click here" />
```

And then, you can read "x:Name" attribute in code behind:

```
MyButton.AutomationId = nameof(MyButton);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer... Yeah this isn’t in the custom (parent) control, I may as well just add an automated id.

Comment: Sorry Jules if I did not get your point, maybe you can use of some events or reflection code to achieve what you want ?

Comment: My aim is not to have to add automated Ids everywhere, whether that’s in xaml or in c#. I am genuinely creating ui tests. So I can’t use events. The automated id needs to be available before an action.

Comment: Then if it is for UI Tests purposes, I personally manage them in a RESX file, so that I can easily share the same AutomationIds between my Views and my UITest project.
Otherwise, I can see there are some other technics like in this [code sample](https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/6e67372cde7e5167a7f2296b6a22bbf6176b9fa8/Src/UITestSampleApp.Shared/Constants/AutomationIdConstants.cs#L3).

Comment: I’d be interested in finding out how static resources can be autocompleted in xaml, I’ve done a lot of work generating constants from image files name and app.xaml using build tasks. Be great to all ply this to c# constants. I’ve used the + syntax for my image file name constants in xaml.